# Tensorflow Keras Metrics Not showing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a simple Neural Network

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, MaxPool2D
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16,(3,3),padding='same', input_shape=(1,28,28),data_format='channels_first'),
    MaxPooling2D((3,3), data_format='channels_first')
])
print(model.summary())
```

summary of model is

```
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 28, 28)        160       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 9, 9)          0         
=================================================================
Total params: 160
Trainable params: 160
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

and compilation as

```py
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.005)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(),
              tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()]
              )
```

Now when I print Model attributes, it gives an empty list on metrics. Why is it so?

```py
print(f"{model.metrics}\n{model.optimizer},\n,{model.loss}\n{model.optimizer.lr}")
```

This is output

```
[]
<tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam object at 0x000001FB10F2EDC8>,
,<tensorflow.python.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy object at 0x000001FB10F2EEC8>
<tf.Variable 'learning_rate:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=0.005>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I want to see the metrics of my model, as I am passing 2 metrics in which are binary accuracy and mean absolute error. I am not trying to do anything specific, just checking them out.

Comment: I mean more details of your code. Because I ran it and it works for me.

Comment: I wonder why it is not working for me

Comment: This is issue in TF 2.2 version. I opened [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40030) issue in github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40030) is a bug in Tensorflow version 2.2.0. Might be fixed later

Comment: I can still reproduce this error using the link's author's code. Any updates?

Answer (score 2):

The model will show metrics after training.

So just run `model.fit` or `model.train_on_batch` and then try again to print. The metrics should appear.

[Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40030).